# ¿Como puedo guardar un string en cada iteración de un ciclo forEach en PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos antes que nada gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios, quiero lograr lo siguiente en cada iteración de un ciclo forEach quiero almacenar el resultado en una variable de manera que al final del recorrido mi variable debe tener todos los resultados del ciclo foreach escribo el cogido que tengo hecho para explicarme mejor.

```
<?php

$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
$consulta = null;
$colums = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];

foreach ($colums as $campo)
    {
        foreach($request as $rows){
           $consulta = $campo . '=' . $rows;
        }
    }

var_dump($consulta);
```

El resultado de este ciclo es el siguiente:

```
"updated_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00"
```

Y lo que yo busco generar es algo como lo siguiente:

```
id=1, nombre='darinel cigarroa', edad='24', created_at='16/12/21', updated_at='16/12/21'
```

¿Como puedo hacer un tipo push de cada iteración en cada ciclo para llegar al resultado?
Les agradezco de ante mano las respuestas y los comentarios, cualquier tipo de ayuda me es util y se agradece.
El siguiente código es repuesta de Rodrigo logra el cometido de la pregunta más sin embargo repite el campo por cada columna este es el código:

```
$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
$consulta = "";
$colums = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];

foreach ($colums as $campo)
    {
        foreach($request as $rows){
           $consulta .= $campo . '=' . $rows . ", ";
        }
    }
# El ultimo elemento temrinara en ", "
# Lo eliminaremos usando preg_replace
$consulta = preg_replace("/\s*\,\s*$/", "", $consulta);

print($consulta);
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
id=1, id=darinel cigarroa, id=24, id=2021-12-16 00:00:00, id=2021-12-16 00:00:00, nombre=1, nombre=darinel cigarroa, nombre=24, nombre=2021-12-16 00:00:00, nombre=2021-12-16 00:00:00, edad=1, edad=darinel cigarroa, edad=24, edad=2021-12-16 00:00:00, edad=2021-12-16 00:00:00, created_at=1, created_at=darinel cigarroa, created_at=24, created_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00, created_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00, updated_at=1, updated_at=darinel cigarroa, updated_at=24, updated_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00, updated_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00
```

Esto ya me es más claro si logro resolve enseguida comparto la respuesta, muchas gracias por aportar a mi problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Repuesta editada)

En efecto, los índices se repiten, pero porque usas dos ciclos, sin embargo, si los dos arrays que consultas (tanto `$request` como `$colums`) tienen la misma cantidad de elementos, no necesitas dos ciclos, basta con usar `for` en vez de `foreach`, para obtener el índice que podremos usar para obtener la columna que corresponde a dicho valor

```php
$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
$consulta = [];
$colums = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];

for($i = 0; $i < count($request); $i++) {
    $column = $colums[$i];
    if ($column) array_push($consulta, "$column={$request[$i]}");
}

# Consulta al final es un array, usaremos implode para convertirlo a string
$consulta = implode(", ", $consulta);
print($consulta);
```

Comment: El código logra el cometido que propones, pero repite los campos es decir asigna id a todos los campos luego con nombre y asi consecutivamente, me diste una idea más clara de como lograrlo, actualizare la pregunta con tu aportación, muchas gracias.

Comment: @DarinelCigarroa He actualizado mi respuesta, comprueba si solucioné tu duda.

Comment: Me marca "Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array)" estoy utiliando https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ para realizar las pruebas creo que el metodo implode es el que genera el error.

Comment: @DarinelCigarroa El orden de los parámetros de `implode` fue cambiada en alguna versión de PHP, cambiando el orden de los parámetros debe funcionar, también volví a actualizar mi respuesta para corregir ese error.

Comment: Ramírez el código ha funcionado como esperaba muchas gracias, solo me surgío una duda cuando lo ejecuto efectivamente da la respuesta esperada pero marca el siguiente warning "<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key 5 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>7</b><br />"
¿Esto por que sucede? ¿Es por que se espera un Array? De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero la condición de final de ciclo debería ser solo `<`, porque si es `<=`, en la última iteración da el error que menciona OP. Además, también faltaría encerrar los valores entre comillas para que funcione en una consulta SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que lo que estás buscando es el resultado de aplicar [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php) el cual:

> Crea un nuevo array, usando una matriz para las claves y otra para sus
> valores.

Haciendo esto:

```
$consulta = array_combine($columns,$request);
```

`$consulta` será un array asociativo, cuyas claves serán lo que haya en `$columns` (he corregido, faltaba una `n`) y los valores serán lo que haya en `$request`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
$columns = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];    

$consulta = array_combine($columns,$request);
foreach($consulta as $k=>$v) {
    echo "$k: $v\n";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
id: 1
nombre: darinel cigarroa
edad: 24
created_at: 2021-12-16 00:00:00
updated_at: 2021-12-16 00:00:00
```

Teniendo los datos organizados, puedes leer `$consulta` del modo que quieras, considerando que es un array.

Por ejemplo, si se trata de construir una sentencia `UPDATE`, podrías hacer algo así:

```
$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
$columns = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];    
$consulta = array_combine($columns,$request);
$set="";
foreach($consulta as $k=>$v) {
    $set.=is_numeric($v) ? "$k=$v," : "$k='$v',";
}
$sql=sprintf("UPDATE laTabla SET %s WHERE laColumna=elCriterio",rtrim($set,','));
echo $sql;
```

**Salida:**

```
UPDATE laTabla 
SET 
    id=1,
    nombre='darinel cigarroa',
    edad=24,
    created_at='2021-12-16 00:00:00',
    updated_at='2021-12-16 00:00:00' 
WHERE laColumna=elCriterio
```

Aquí simplemente hemos aprovechado la estructura del array para crear la parte `SET` de la consulta `UPDATE` y, dado que dentro del bucle sobraría una coma (la del último valor en el array), la quitamos con [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rtrim.php). Además, usamos [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php), que para estos casos ayuda bastante a simplificar el código, creando contenido dinámico.

Sea como sea, esto es a modo de ejemplo, para que comprendas que usando las herramientas adecuadas puedes crear cualquier contenido de forma dinámica con mucha facilidad. Realmente, para este caso lo mejor sería crear una **consulta preparada**, donde la adaptación sería aún más sencilla (usando las herramientas adecuadas), siendo además la práctica recomendada a nivel de la seguridad de los datos y de la optimización del código.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @A.Cedano, lo que realmente busco es un estring para poder hacer un update a mi base de datos.

Comment: @DarinelCigarroa teniendo los datos organizados, puedes armar lo que quieras a partir de ellos. Ahora te muestro la forma de construir un `UPDATE`, aunque para esto deberías crear una consulta preparada (este es otro tema, pues trata de la seguridad a nivel de la base de datos).

Comment: perfecto a lo mejor abra una nueva pregunta acerca de esto en dado caso la lógica que tengo planteada falle te agradezco mucho el aporte.

Comment: @DarinelCigarroa revisa lo que he puesto al final de la respuesta, por si te puede servir en un futuro. Una vez los datos organizados adecuadamente será más fácil producir cualquier salida con ellos, según lo que necesites en ese momento.

Comment: Interesante respuesta, me extraña que no hayas mencionado lo que hace `rtrim()` y para qué está ahí. Esa aclaración vendría muy bien, especialmente para novatos.

Comment: @Triby no le di mucha importancia al considerar que en un contexto real este código debería terminar en una consulta preparada, pero tienes razón, sirve mucho hacer referencia a las funciones usadas para fines de comprensión y profundización en el lenguaje. He editado la respuesta atendiendo a tu acertada sugerencia. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano excelente aporte me ha servido de mucho al igual comprender que a veces me puedo complicar de una manera teniendo más opciones, gracias por tu respuesta estoy seguro que a más de uno le servira.